# How to get the full host name in Javascript including HTTP?

Tags: javascript, url, hostname

I have a problem with getting the host name in Javascript, I have used the code below:

```
document.location.replace("http://"+ document.location.host + "/another-page")
```

The code works fine, it gets the host name and replaces the documents URL with the new one.

The problem is with the `document.location.host`, it only returns the host like this: **www.xxx.com** without the **http** part. This is not a scalable way of doing it, cause locally the site runs on http and on the server it runs on https. I don't want to manually change the http part.

So is there a better sollution to automaticly get the full name of a host including http(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is this `location.origin` what you are looking for?

or you can get protocol only using this `location.protocol`

See more here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location

```js
console.log('location.protocol -', location.protocol);
console.log('location.origin -', location.origin);
```